# Jquery process on a client suitescript to be run after other processes finish

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a client script which is redirecting to a url.
This client script works in conjunction with a suitelet.

I was wanting to add jQuery('#submitter').click() to the script but only after the page has redirected.

Is that possible?
The client script:

```js
    /**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define([
    "N/record",
    "N/runtime",
    "N/url",
    "N/log",
    "N/ui/dialog",
    "N/search",
    "N/currentRecord",
], function (record, search, runtime, url, log, dialog, currentRecord) {
    /**
     * @param {ClientScriptContext.pageInit} context
     */

    function pageInit(context) {}

    function executeRecurring(context) {

        var pageUrl =
            "https://tstdrv.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/journal.nl?id=20916&e=T&void=T&memdoc=0&transform=timebill"

        var url = new URL(pageUrl)
    
        window.location.href = url

        
        window.location.assign(
            "https://tstdrv.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/journal.nl?id=20916&e=T&void=T&memdoc=0&transform=timebill"
        )
    }

    var customSubmit = function returnFields(context) {
        record.submitFields.promise({
            type: record.Type.JOURNAL_ENTRY,
            id: 20916, //the internal id of one record
            values: {
                memo: "reversal",
            },
        })
    }



    return {
        pageInit: pageInit,
        executeRecurring: executeRecurring,
        customSubmit: customSubmit,

    }
})
```

I was wanting to add the jQuery in place of the custom submit (which is currently not doing anything). I have found this doesn't trigger through on the page

Ideally, if I could get it to work on this one record, I was planning on including logic to make it loop through a list of internal ids and perform the same action (submit the record to the database before moving to the next record)

Comment: Once you have naviagated away from a page you are no longer running that client script.  Setting location.href is not a hashchange event. For looping through a list of ids you probably want to review scheduled and map/reduce scripts.

Comment: Thanks Bknights. Would a scheduled or map reduce script allow navigation to another url? I tried to use a scheduled script with N/redirect though from what I can tell, it wasn't possible to navigate to a specific url and then submit the record

Comment: No it would not. It looks like you are trying to mimic the steps a user would take to accomplish a task. Generally the way to do whatever you are attempting via the API itself.

Comment: What I am trying to do is: save a journal after navigating to a particular url with parameters e=T; void=T; transform=timebill & id=journal id(for the jnl I am trying to void), I have found this is the only way to void journals created to post time entries. The void time UI function only works if you know which time entries you want to void (in this case, I only know the journals). From my testing using n/record; N/transaction and a few other modules, I can't find anything in the API that does this

Comment: You might want to play with the timebill retract action in the `N/action` module.  I haven't done much with timebills but that looks like it might work. There is also the `N/transaction` module that has a transaction.void method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion BKnights. I will look into N/action. I have looked at N/transaction though timebill is not a supported record type